# Custom Tables: How does SPSS treat multi response sets differently from categorical vars?

Tags: r, statistics, spss, significance, hypothesis-test

SPSS treats [multi response sets](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/tables/nt_mult_response_intro.dita?lang=en) differently from categorical vars when it comes to z-tests in custom tables. I assume that this behaviour is linked to the overlap of the responses, but I cannot figure out how.

So, **how does SPSS do z-testing when it comes to multi response sets (MRsets)?**

My goal is to reproduce SPSS z-test for MRsets in R, but I cannot figure out what SPSS actually does. Normally, SPSS custom table z-testing is just the same as

```
prop.test(c(proportion1,proportion2),c(columnSum1,columSum2),"two.sided",correct=F)
```

but it is different with MRsets, obviously.

To make this clear, please take a look at this categorical versus MRset comparison.

---

### Categorical var z-test (C & D columns are not different according to z-test)

- Categorical dataset (no overlap, 3623 cases): [Download dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zViumIZvWcT3ZDR0ctT2pZTE0)
- Categorical overlap matrix (no overlap): [image]
- Categorcial z-test SPSS syntax

  ```
  CTABLES
    /VLABELS VARIABLES=splitVar catVar DISPLAY=DEFAULT
    /TABLE splitVar [C][COUNT F40.0] BY catVar [C]
    /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=splitVar catVar ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE
    /COMPARETEST TYPE=PROP ALPHA=0.05 ADJUST=NONE ORIGIN=COLUMN INCLUDEMRSETS=NO CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE.
  ```
- Categorcial z-test output:
  [image]
- R reproduction for C<->D z-test (first row): http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=p4gw9ftk

  ```
  "Categorical var z-test"
  "Doing a proportions test for first row (splitVar=1) and columns C and D"
  prop.test(c(198,242), c(198+35,242+65), alternative="two.sided", correct=F )
  "As we see, there are no significant differences in the proportions on an alpha=0.05 level"
  ```

---

### MRset z-test (identical numbers in table, but different z-test result: significant differences in C & D columns)

- MRset dataset (overlaps included, 2404 cases): [Download dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9zViumIZvWccnk1RjJSQWJ3Zkk)
- MRset overlap matrix: [image]
- MRset z-test output:[image]
- MRset z-test SPSS syntax:

  ```
  CTABLES
      /VLABELS VARIABLES=splitVar $MySet DISPLAY=DEFAULT
      /TABLE splitVar [C] BY $MySet [C][COUNT F40.0]
      /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=splitVar ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE
      /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=$MySet  EMPTY=INCLUDE
      /COMPARETEST TYPE=PROP ALPHA=0.05 ADJUST=NONE ORIGIN=COLUMN INCLUDEMRSETS=YES CATEGORIES=ALLVISIBLE.
  ```
- R reproduction for C<->D z-test (first row): http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=GAhnnrv0

  ```
  "MRset z-test"
  "Doing a proportions test for first row (splitVar=1) and columns C and D"
  overlap_splitvar1_CD <- 53
  overlap_splitvar2_CD <- 9
  prop.test(c(198-overlap_splitvar1_CD,242-overlap_splitvar1_CD), c(198+35-overlap_splitvar1_CD-overlap_splitvar2_CD,242+65-overlap_splitvar1_CD-overlap_splitvar2_CD), alternative="two.sided", correct=F )
  "As we see, there are still no significant differences in the proportions on an alpha=0.05 level. In contrast, SPSS does detect a difference. Why?"
  ```

---

As you can see from the MRset R code, even a subtraction of overlap cases does not help. Maybe it is linked to weighting or something? **Thanks so much for ideas.**

Possibly helpful link: [A Note on Weights and Multiple Response Sets](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/ctables_teststats_multresponse_note.htm?lang=en)

Comment: A user at CrossValidated has given a potentially useful answer, hinting at the SPSS algorithms document:

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163712/custom-tables-how-does-spss-treat-multi-response-sets-differently-from-categori?noredirect=1#comment311297_163712

Comment: I am working on this and report back once I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the [Bonferroni adjustment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/%23!/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_ctables_pairwise_comparisons_proportions_and_means_comparetest.htm) that is being applied by `CTABLES` potentially?

Comment: Good thought, but such a p-value correction is never indicated by SPSS and is also set to "NONE" in the SPSS syntax in both cases.